# Install SDL2 for Haskell with stack on Windows

Tags: haskell, sdl-2, haskell-stack

I'm trying to use SDL2 with stack. I followed [these instructions](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskellgamedev/comments/4jpthu/windows_sdl2_is_now_almost_painless_via_stack/) . `stack exec -- pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2` runs smoothly. But when I try to install SDL2 by typing `stack install sdl2`, the compilation fails with the error

`` undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard' ``

I guess this has to do with mingw and some options that should be activated, namely `-fstack-protector`, from what I saw on other forum posts. However in this case, I can't add this option to mingw since everything is going on under the hood.

How can I install SDL2 properly with stack ?

Comment: Apparently is due to a version mismatch. Follow [this](https://github.com/haskell-game/sdl2/issues/277#issuecomment-1339145721) comment for a workaround

Comment: SDL2 works fine on my machine. Whenever I add another dep like sdl2-image I get the  same error.

I'm using Stack, if I add sdl2 to package.yaml, everything works fine.

Comment: In my case the work around proposed in the link sent by @Ismor worked fine. Thanks